# How to use OpenGraph tags on auth-required app?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, facebook-canvas

I have an iframe canvas app that requires accepting of an auth dialog before use, i.e. from a browser point of view, all requests are immediately redirected to the auth dialog if the user has not already accepted them.

This means that the Facebook parser cannot read the OpenGraph tags on my page because it can never get past the authorisation point.

In a broader scale, this problem would also occur on any page that requires a login before viewing.

What would be the best way to work around this issue?

One solution I have is to check if the Organization that the client IP address belongs to is Facebook and if so let it in without authorisation, and display a page with no content except the OG tags. This is fine for robot programs access from Facebook, but what happens if an employee tries; I don't want my app to be disabled because someone from the policy team cannot properly verify the app.

As to why I need OG tags - users regularly share the link to the app and it looks bad with just a URL as the title and description and no image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow Facebook's URL scraper to view your objects.

Best way to do this is to check for the string 'facebookexternalhit' in the useragent string. If present, return a stripped down HTML page containing the OG tags for the Facebook's scraper to read.